# Can't get AJAX url to point to the right file (SLIM)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, slim

First off I know this is probably sooo bad and wrong but I sadly have very little time and I need things to work, even if they are awful from a development point of view. I intend to learn the proper way to do things once I'm done with this project.

I am trying to get AJAX to work with the SLIM framework. My file structure is (to be revamped, anyway):

[image]

I'm trying to call DBController.php via ajax from script.js. Here is my Route.php:

```
  $app->get('/home', function ($request, $response) {
      return $this->view->render($response, 'home.html');
  });

  $app->get('/accounts', function ($request, $response) use ($app) {
    $_SESSION['DBControllerFunction'] = 'SelectAccounts';
    return $this->view->render($response, 'accounts.html');
  });
```

Here is my ajax call

```
  $.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/accounts",
    success: function (data) {
      alert ('Success!');
    }
  });
```

I've tried setting the URL to loads of different paths, but I'm so confused. Essentially I would like my DBController.php to pass table values to my JS so I can render them in HTML with KnockoutJS, but I'm just so confused. Thanks for nay help!

Comment: You should check your ajax request via developer tool on the browser.

Comment: You execute POST request to /accounts but you defined GET only in your code. Also, $_SESSION should defined as global if you want to use it in the function. This is a bad practice though.